# com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationMOMProviderException: errors.mom.USG_MOM_SERVICE_PROVIDER_ERROR

Tags: sabre

Am trying to call EnhancedSeatMapRQ from SoapUI, but, am getting this response. Anyone knows why?

The reponse says 'USG_MOM_SERVICE_PROVIDER_ERROR', and am not able to find any explanation in any Sabre document for it. I am able to make a different API call, but, not this one.

Ignore the security token.. I changed it for this posting

Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="2.0" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <eb:ConversationId>webservices.support@sabre.com</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">openjawtech.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>8CB9</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:Service>getReservationRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>getReservationRQ</eb:Action>
          <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2020-06-01T11:15:12Z</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:TimeToLive>2020-06-01T11:15:12Z</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>

       <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESB!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!LB!1111111111!11111</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>

        </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>

<ns6:EnhancedSeatMapRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v02" xmlns:ns2="http://opentravel.org/common/message/v02" xmlns:ns3="http://opentravel.org/common/v02" xmlns:ns4="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_00" xmlns:ns5="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/v1" xmlns:ns6="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/v5" xmlns:ext="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/diagnostics/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/v5 ../schema_v5/schema/EnhancedSeatMap_5_0_0.xsd">
    <ns6:SeatMapQueryEnhanced>
        <ns6:RequestType>Payload</ns6:RequestType>
        <ns6:Flight destination="SAN" origin="IAD">
            <ns6:DepartureDate>2019-06-26</ns6:DepartureDate>
            <ns6:Operating carrier="UA">646</ns6:Operating>
            <ns6:Marketing carrier="UA">646</ns6:Marketing>
            <ns6:ArrivalDate>2019-06-26</ns6:ArrivalDate>
        </ns6:Flight>
    </ns6:SeatMapQueryEnhanced>
</ns6:EnhancedSeatMapRQ>

</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">openjawtech.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>8CB9</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>webservices.support@sabre.com</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service>getReservationRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>7914342588700530193</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2019-01-24T16:21:10</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESB!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!1111111111!11111</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Server.SystemFailure</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Service provider invocation failure</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationMOMProviderException: errors.mom.USG_MOM_SERVICE_PROVIDER_ERROR</StackTrace>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you seem to be sending an invalid payload (missing booking class, POS). This worked for me with flight 231:

```
<EnhancedSeatMapRQ xmlns="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/v3">
<SeatMapQueryEnhanced>
        <RequestType>Payload</RequestType>
        <Flight destination="SAN" origin="IAD">
        <DepartureDate>2019-06-26</DepartureDate>
        <Operating carrier="UA">231</Operating>
        <Marketing carrier="UA">231</Marketing>
        <ArrivalDate>2019-06-26</ArrivalDate>
    </Flight>
    <CabinDefinition>
        <RBD>Y</RBD>
    </CabinDefinition>
    <FareAvailQualifiers PaxType="ADT" quantity="1">
        <TravellerID>1</TravellerID>
    </FareAvailQualifiers>
    <POS>
        <PCC>your pcc</PCC>
    </POS>
</SeatMapQueryEnhanced>
</EnhancedSeatMapRQ>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/seat_map)
Please try the same with Service Action Code: EnhancedSeatMapRQ

Hope it helps.
P.